# Extend SELECT without dropping the default `*`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a gem which exposes scopes with computed columns. The implementation is not important, I can illustrate my problem with simple examples.

The default `select` of a query is `*`:

```
User.unscoped.to_sql
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
```

However, once an explicit `select` is done, this default is overwritten:

```
User.select(:created_at).to_sql
# => SELECT created_at FROM "users"
```

Subsequent calls are cumulative:

```
User.select(:created_at).select(:created_at).to_sql
# => SELECT created_at, updated_at FROM "users"
```

Here's the clicker: I'd like to add a column to the SELECT clause, however, the default must be preserved. If an explicit `select` is present, this works just fine:

```
User.select(:created_at).compute_some_column.to_sql
# => SELECT created_at, "users"."some_column" FROM "users"
```

But if no explicit `select` is present, then you won't get anything but the computed column:

```
User.compute_some_column.to_sql
# => SELECT "users"."some_column" FROM "users"
```

Okay, I can always include `*` in my `compute_some_column` scope, but this would be an ugly hack which might result in columns being fetched multiple times:

```
User.compute_some_column.compute_another_column.to_sql
# => SELECT "users".*, "users"."some_column", "users".*, "users"."another_column" FROM "users"
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a sql string into the select method like this: User.select(:id,'*')